# How to do stuff with actionbar sherlock icon on top of left side?

Tags: java, android, menu, tabs, actionbarsherlock

[image]

I want to implement on click listener on icon of sherlock actionbar show in above image. How can I do this? Please anyone can give this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity,

in your onCreate()

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and then

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        //do your stuff here
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```